# If we know the direction of the sum of vectors $\frac{\sum_1^\infty w_i}{\|\sum_1^\infty w_i\|}=u$, how can we calculate the expection of the vectos?

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, expected-value

Given a set of vectors $w_i, i\in[1,\infty]$. If we know the direction of the sum of them as
$$\frac{\sum_1^\infty w_i}{\|\sum_1^\infty w_i\|}=u$$
How can we prove the expectation of vector $$\mathbb{E}\frac{w_i}{\|w_i\|}=u$$

Intuitively, the results seem to be. Because if the expectation of the direction is not $u$, the final sum will not be at the direction of $u$. But I don't know how can we rigorously prove this?

Comment: The statement as written is not correct; consider the vectors (1,0) and (0,2).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks for your comments. I want to assume we have infinity vectors here.

Comment: Law of large numbers

Comment: @Youem Thanks very much for your hint. I know the Law of large numbers but I don't know how to apply it to vector directions. Would it be possible to give more details about this?

Comment: If you want to assume an infinite sum, take the rest of the vectors as zero; if you want them to be non-zero, then a different approach works — take the vectors as (1, 0) and then (0, 1/2), (0, 1/4); the direction of the sum is (proportional to) (1,1) but the expectation of the directions is (0,1).

Comment: @maple I added an answer explaining what I wanted to say. I also added a probabilistic context to the problem via my answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

To put the question rigorously, assume you have $W$ a random vector. $\left(W_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ are independent observations of $W$. If $\mathbb E\left\|W\right\|^2 < \infty$ then by the law of large numbers: $$\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n W_k = \mathbb E[W]$$ and the ratio that you are looking for:
$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^\infty W_k}{\left\|\sum_{k=1}^\infty W_k\right\|} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n W_k}{\left\|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n W_k\right\|} = \frac{\mathbb E\left[W\right]}{\left\|\mathbb E[W]\right\|}.$$

This value in general is different from $\mathbb E\left[\frac{W}{\|W\|}\right]$. I would say that the answer at your question is **NO**.

---

- Studying when $\mathbb E\left[\frac{W}{\|W\|}\right] = \frac{\mathbb E\left[W\right]}{\left\|\mathbb E[W]\right\|}$:

Moreover, (thanks to the comment of @aschepler) using the fact that $u\mapsto \left\|u\right\|$ is strongly convex (I am assuming that we are working with $\left\|\cdot \right\|_2$). $$\left\|\mathbb E\left[\frac{W}{\left\|W\right\|}\right]\right\| \le \mathbb E\left[\left\|\frac{W}{\left\|W\right\|}\right\|\right] = 1$$

with equality holds if and only if $\frac{W}{\left\|W\right\|}$ is a constant vector. So $W = X \mathbf u$ with $X$ is a nonnegative random variable and $\mathbf u$ a unitary vector.

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for your detailed explanation. It is great but a little bit goes against my intuition. In my intuition, as we add vectors $w_i$, it is expected to finally point toward the direction of its expected vector. Is there anything wrong with this intuition?

Comment: No not at all it is correct to say the it points toward the direction of its expected vector. However, the argument of saying that the direction of expected vector is equal to the expected direction is false.

Comment: @maple By the way in my answer your intuition is proven to be true (see the limit of the ratio).

Comment: Example: If $W = (2,0)$ with probability $\frac 12$ and $W = (0,4)$ with probability $\frac 12$, then $\frac{\mathbb{E}[W]}{\|\mathbb{E}[W]\|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(1,2)$, but $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{W}{\|W\|}\right] =\left(\frac 12, \frac 12\right)$.

Comment: @aschepler Please don't hesitate to add the example that you provide to the answer if you think it will make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for @aschepler 's great example. Now I understand that they are two different quantities. I guess only if the norm of $W_i$ are equal we can get $\mathbb E\left[\frac{W}{\|W\|}\right]=\frac{\mathbb E\left[W\right]}{\left\|\mathbb E[W]\right\|}$. Usually, they are not eaual.

Comment: The only way they can be equal is for a distribution with a single constant vector. Otherwise, $\left\|\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{W}{\|W\|}\right]\right\| < 1$.

Comment: Yes that is true. One can prove it using the Jensen inequality, I assume and strong convexity?

Comment: @aschepler the vector is not obliged to be constant. But it should have a constant direction. I edit my answer to include that.

Comment: Or, $$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{W}{\|W\|}\right] \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{W}{\|W\|}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{W}{\|W\|} \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{W}{\|W\|}\right]\right] = \int \left(\frac{W}{\|W\|} \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{W}{\|W\|}\right]\right) p(W)\, dW \leq \left\|\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{W}{\|W\|}\right]\right\|$$

Comment: @aschepler that works as well. But does it give the equality case?

Comment: @Youem Yes, it gives equality only if $P\left(\frac{W}{\|W\|} = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{W}{\|W\|}\right]\right) = 1$, implying the vectors with non-zero probability have a common direction.

Comment: That's true! Well done!

Comment: Thanks very much for the great discussion and I really learned a lot. I didn't realize that the requirement for equality holds is quite strict before. It is really helpful for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain if this answer is correct, but I believe it gets to what OP wanted, based on the OP?

I think I understand what is being asked here, so let me reveal what I believe the question intended to be.

Let's start with the finite case.

The sum of $n$ finite vectors $w_i,\ i\in \{1,\ldots, n\},\ $ is $\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n w_i.$ Since a vector has magnitude and direction, the vector $\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n w_i$ can be colloquially said to " have direction $\ \lambda\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n w_i,$ " where $\lambda$ can be any constant, because scalar multiplication of a vector doesn't affect the vector's *direction*.

The *expectation* of the vectors $w_i,\ i\in \{1,\ldots, n\},\ $ is by definition, their average, which is given by the formula: $$ \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}{n}. $$

So in the finite case, the direction and expectation of a finite set of vectors can be the same vector: just set $$\lambda = \frac{1}{n}. $$

Maybe the following is easier-to-understand summary of the result so far:

> The expectation vector of a finite set of vectors $w_i,\ i\in \{1,\ldots, n\},\ $ is in the same direction as the sum of these $n$
> vectors.

$$$$

Ok, so now we get to the OP, which I believe is simply asking about the countably infinite case:

> Is it true that, for a countably infinite set of vectors $w_i,\ i\in\{1,\ldots, n\},\ $ the expectation vector is in the same direction as
> the sum of these vectors?

An immediate problem arises with this question, as the sum of infinitely many vectors may not itself be a vector, because this infinite sum may not converge within the vector space. Furthermore, the expectation vector of infinitely many vectors might also not converge. Therefore, we must standardise the sum of the direction vectors, and use limits in order for the question to be meaningful. I believe this is what is meant from OP:

Is the direction of the sum of the vectors, as we add them up in the order they are given,

$$\lambda\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}{\left \vert \left \vert \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n w_i \right \vert \right \vert },$$

equal to the direction of the expectation of all the vectors:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}{n }.$$

Whilst it is true that neither of these limits necessarily converge, what I think is being sought after is, assuming they both do converge, *when are they equal?* (i.e. in the same direction)?

Surely this can only occur if there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left \vert \left \vert \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n w_i \right \vert \right \vert}{n} = c.$$

Comment: I suspect I'm wrong here actually, but not completely sure either way... Probably complete nonsense. Uh-oh..